# Set Request Method for PHP Rest Api

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm building rest APIs in Php and I want to set a request method for each Api from the .htaccess. Since in Php rest Api can accessed whatever the request method is. I used this method

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteRule /?user/list api/user/list.php [NC,L]
```

but it didn't work it still can be accessed when I send a post request.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST`

Comment: @mitkosoft I tried and works thanks. But how I can set multiple request methods?

Comment: You shouldn't have to state `!POST` with the above rule in order to exclude POST requests, since you are already matching GET _only_. But where is this `.htaccess` file located? You are not using any string anchors on the `RewriteRule` pattern, so this is potentially matching too much.

Comment: .htaccess is located in the root project. RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET works fine but when I add the same condition for OPTIONS it allows all methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disabling `MultiViews`. If MultiViews is enabled then it will completely bypass the mod_rewrite directives and issue an internal subrequest for `list.php` regardless of the request method.

Your `RewriteRule` *pattern* is also also too general - it looks like it would generate a rewrite loop?!

> `.htaccess` is located in the root project.

By that, I assume you mean it's in the directory where `/api` is a subdirectory?

In which case try the following:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =GET
RewriteRule ^api/user/list$ api/user/list.php [L]
```

The `=` in `=GET` makes it an *exact match* string comparison.

You shouldn't need the `NC` flag, unless you specifically need to allow mixed case requests?